# Does Keeping a Cookie "Whitelist" Slow Down Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, performance, browser, cookies

I use Chrome so that, by default, I block all cookies, but then "whitelist" sites I use often, either fully accepting its cookies or by selecting the "clear on exit" option.

As a result, I have created two impossibly long lists. Checking on Chrome's `Settings > Privacy & security > Site settings > Cookies and site data`, the items contained on the lists "Sites that can always use cookies" and "Always clear cookies when windows are closed" run in the hundreds.

**My question is:**
Does this slow down Chrome more than allowing all cookies to be saved?

It seems obvious to me that, without blocking cookies as I currently do, and unless cookies are cleared often, there will be very rapidly a significantly large amount of cookies stored. Is, however, anything *inherently* slower in maintaining such large whitelists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open developer tools and go to the *Network* tab it will show you all web requests including how many cookies in each request, the size of the request and the total time for the request. At the bottom of the Network tab it will also show the webpage total for kB transferred, MB in resources and time to load the page.
There is a specific filter "Has blocked cookies" which may be useful somehow as well.

I would think scenario B, with cookies being blocked and specific websites whitelisted would be more of a negative impact on webpage performance. While storing data is commonly used to track users for ads and such it is also used to remember data for better usability.

For example, you are on a website and logging in takes you to the login page. It would be nice for the login page to take you back to the page you were previously on.

The type/version of browser may be stored in a cookie to let the website know to use web features like [lazy loading](https://web.dev/lazy-loading-images/#images-inline-native). Storing this information would make the webpage load faster since it would defer loading images until they were in your view vs loading everything at once.

Blocking cookies would seem to make web pages work harder and have worse performance than the milliseconds storing/accessing a cookie would take. The webpage is still going to try to use the API to work with cookies and whatever Javascript or backend framework to do this will load either way.

Answer (score 0):

Slower, yes, but by how much? This is for you to say.

If you have not noticed any major slow-down, then it may only be on the order of
milliseconds, so not worth worrying about.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was hoping for something a bit more objective than my having noticed a slow-down – which can also depend on other factors.
To put it this way, if we assume two scenarios: A) no blocking, no whitelists, Chrome has 100 cookies stored. B) blocking all cookies, the very same 100 cookies are stored because the associated websites are whitelisted. Is there any way to measure whether B causes a greater slow-down than A?

Comment: You may use a profiler product on Chrome, that can give you such answers. Or you can use a more primitive method such as a stop-watch. The primitive method may not give any result, because most likely the difference would be too small for humans.